# Python 2.7 IDLE cannot reload

Tags: python, import, reload, python-idle

I am using `Python 2.7.6` and `IDLE` in `Windows 8.` I am doing the following: `import count`, then modify something in count, then `reload(count)`, and the changes are not updated. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Care to post a minimal bit of code demonstrating the problem?  That might get you useful feedback sooner.  (Remember to add: what happened, and what did you expect instead.)

Comment: `import count` `x = count.count([0,1])` `x.add()`. Then I modified the add function. `reload(count)` `x.add()`. It does not work.

Comment: When I say that it does not work, I mean that the module is not reloaded.

Comment: Did you reassign `x` before trying `x.add()` again? Even though you reloaded the module, `x` won't change unless you reassign it.

Comment: That was the problem! I was not reassigning x. That worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, when you reload a module, any old references to the module or anything from the module are not affected.

If you look at the [documentation for reload](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload), you'll see this:

> Other references to the old objects (such as names external to the module) are not rebound to refer to the new objects and must be updated in each namespace where they occur if that is desired.

So if you reload a module, you need to recreate any objects from that module in order to get the changes from the reload.